# No se muestran los datos en las etiquetas <td>

Tags: java, servlets

No logro hacer que los datos se muestren en las etiquetas , los datos se envían al JSP al Servlet y luego este redirecciona algunos al mismo JSP pero no se muestran.

```
 <table style="width: 40%">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Sueldo</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td<c:out value="${nom}"/>></td>
                <td<c:out value="${ape}"/>></td>
                <td<c:out value="${suledo}"/>></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Código del servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //Recibir datos del archivo index.jsp
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombres");
    String apellido = request.getParameter("apellidos");
    String documento = request.getParameter("doc");
    String dtrabajo = request.getParameter("dtrabajo");
    String sueldo = request.getParameter("sueldo");

    int dt = Integer.parseInt(dtrabajo);
    int salario= Integer.parseInt(sueldo);

    request.setAttribute("nom", nombre);
    request.setAttribute("ape", apellido);
    request.setAttribute("sueldo", sueldo);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Comment: Como tienes tu etiqueta <form> ?

Comment: Así:<form action="nominaservlet" method="get">
No me deja agregarlo completo